# Angular2 + Jasmine test: "Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive Foo."

Tags: angular, jasmine

When I try to run the following test with `ng test` it gives me the error shown below.

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

export class Foo {

}

describe('Foo', () => {

    let foo: Foo;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                Foo
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        foo = TestBed.createComponent(Foo).componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(foo).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

`Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive Foo.`

Why does this happen and how can I make it run?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the `@Component` annotation. Try it like this:

```
@Component({
    template: "<div></div>"
})
class Foo {
}
```

Of course you have to import the `Component` class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

PS: I don't think you need to export the `Foo` class from a test module.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same exception as described and could fix it by adding **foo** to the **declarations** section:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                Foo
            ],
            declarations: [
                Foo
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

like @lex82 mentioned, you need to add `@Component`, and like @marco birchler mentioned, you need to add `Foo` to `declarations` list.

*You can compile it, but that's not really needed*

*and you can remove the providers list, because `Foo` is a Component*

```js
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({template: '<div></div>'})
export class Foo { }

describe('Foo', () => {
  let foo: Foo;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Foo]
    });
    foo = TestBed.createComponent(Foo).componentInstance;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(foo).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```